# ASP.NET MVC 5 (VS2013 final) external login from Android fails (loginInfo is null)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-login, google-signin

when I try to external login in my website using Android's default Browser as well as from Chrome Browser on Android - `await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` always returns `null`.

I'm checking both Google and Facebook's authentication. For both I get the usual stuff asking me for my username and password and then I am returned to my website for completion and there I always get null for `AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()`.

The very same code works fine locally in debug.

Also, it used to worked fine up until two or three days earlier.

what might be the problem and hopefully the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got same problem,and I found I forgot to enable my google Api+.

and make sure your website is host under https

go to see the Microsoft reference
[official reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)